# eclipse : failed to load main-class attribute manifest

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

When I export a jar file from eclipse and run it with cmd from this method

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

this message appears to me

```
failed to load main-class attribute manifest from "filename"
```

I found some suggestions online to include a manifest file. I don't know how to create one. Can someone explain how to fix this problem in detail

Comment: Yes i did from export then i chosen as jar file

Comment: Try to avoid providing superfluous information (like "I searched far and wide but didn't understand anything", or "I'm a newbie") - it does not help clarify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
jar cfe filename.jar MainClass *.class
```

instead. it seems you didn't prepare a textfile with Main-Class: "filenameClass" beforehand.

Comment: i dont know how to prepare it

Comment: and will a prepare it for each class ?

Comment: just use the command I gave. otherwise you'd have to create a manifest.txt , put Main-Class: "fileNameMainClass" inside (fileNameMainClass changed accordingly) , and run jar cfm filename.jar manifest.txt *.class

Comment: ok if my file was hello.jar could you tell me what will i write in manifest file ?

Comment: use "jar cfe hello.jar MainClass *.class" and you're fine without manifest.txt

Comment: ok i will try your solution tommorrow when i get to the eclipse on my pc

Comment: but this problem didnt face me when i had had eclipse luna and jdk 8 and now i have eclipse helios and jdk 6

Comment: the mistake was from me i exported the file as JAR not a runnable jar and your solution is right :)